# Cut-Scene Archive in Mass Effect Series

Tags: mass-effect-series

I'd like to review some scenes to refresh my own memory, straight from the source, regarding some of the events in the Mass Effect games.  Is there some sort of cut-scene archive in any of the games, for this purpose?  Or can this only be done by re-playing the sections of the game I'm interested in?

NOTE:  I'm playing on the PS3 now, so I'm not optimistic about finding a good answer for my platform.  But I'd be interested to know if at least the PC version had some way to access previously-viewed videos.

Comment: There was a ["comic"](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/12/17/mass-effect-2s-ps3-exclusive-comic-how-it-works/) of sorts included with PS3 copies of ME2, which did a quick rundown of the events of the first ME game.  Other than that, I think you'd have to hit up youtube and do some searching.  Maybe a Let's Play?

Comment: Based on the review of the comic you linked, I don't think it has the level of detail I'd be looking for.  Fortunately, for the purpose I was originally seeking, the Mass Effect Wiki has served me well.  I was trying to figure out when we originally discovered that Liara was pureblood - something that kinda felt out of left field when it was mentioned in Mass Effect 2, until the Wiki reminded me that we *had* discussed it with her in the first game.

Comment: There are a few "Mass Effect Videos" on youtube, which include a full playthrough of all of the cutscenes in the game in a movie format - but these do not let you select the individual conversation options, you're stuck with the options that they chose when making the videos.

Answer (score 1):

Download [this](http://www.bikplayer.com/download.html), after it's installed open it and open your ME directory>BioGame>Movies
and watch all of the cutscenes as you like. This will work with any game with .bik cutscenes.

Comment: OMG Bink! I can remember back in, like, 1999, we wanted to compress a class movie and one of my friends suggested using Bink, since it was pretty lossless with respect to our other choices and also free. It pleases me to see that it's made it this far (and that I get to pull a Hipster Gamer/Internet-Person and say I knew about that before it got super-popular).

Comment: N.B. - many of the cutscenes in that folder are loading screen loops and shuttles descending on planets. That said, if you want to see pieces of the various endings, or clips of some of the battles, this is the way to go. Otherwise, it's to YouTube with you to find playthrough videos, because that's the main place you'll find what you're looking for.